# How to bind angular controller with existing object

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have js object like:

```
var Test = function () {

  var x;
  var y;

  this.start = function() {
    //some action
    if ( x > y) { 
      x = x* 10; // now update angular $scope.x
    }
  };

  this.end = function() {
    //other action
  };


  function anotherAction() {

  };
};
```

And I have an angular controller

```
testModule.controller('TestCtrl', function ($scope, $location) {
  var test = new Test();

  //$scope.x = value from test
}
```

I want to bind angular controller with `Test` entity. E.g. I want to catch, when `test.end()` will be invoked and get returned value or pass value from `test.end()` to angular. Is it possible?

**Update:**

x and y can be updated in test.start() method, I want to pass new value (x or y) to angular controller after updating x or y. (listen x or y for changes like angular listen model)

How can I catch event in angular?

Sorry for newbie question.

Comment: add your object to a custom service and inject the service into the controller. the service will call `new` for you and maintain a singleton state take a look [here](http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.13/docs/api/AUTO.$provide#methods_service)

Comment: @DavidChase, updated question. Is it still correct way?

Comment: you want to wrap in a service and you can broadcast or emit events from that service to your controller...etc does that make sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make Test a factory or service that exposes your x/y fields:

```
var Test = function() {

     var values = {
          x: 0,
          y: 0
      };

      return {
          values: values,
          start: function () {
              values.x++;
              values.y++;
          },
          end: function () { }
      }
}

angular.service('Test', Test);
```

Now in your scope, you can say:

```
angular.controller('TestController', ['$scope', 'TestSvc', function(
        $scope, testSvc) {
    $scope.test = testSvc.values;
});
```

Anywhere in your app that uses TestSvc will be able to access the updated values of x/y through TestSvc.values

(Edit: forgot the .values reference in controller)
(Edit 2: changed the body of the Test function, as it wouldn't run properly as shown originally)

Comment: could you also answer, how to catch document event in angular controller? $scope.$on('eventName', function() {}) doesn't work for me

Comment: No room in here for a full answer, but a document event is a DOM concern, so you should not be doing that in your controller...I would probaly look at putting that capture into a directive, then using the directive to notify the containig controller

Comment: Could you put your answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21926347/listen-document-event-in-angular-controller ?

Comment: $scope.test in controller will be always x:0, y:0, even x and y changed in test function

Comment: I apologize...I originally typed my answer right here w/o running it. I slighly changed the Test function, as it would not run properly before. I also ran it myself this time :)