# Listen document event in angular controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How to catch event in angular's controller?

I have document level events, so I need to catch event in angular controller, is it possible?

**Update**

I have standalone js file with handling of some actions from camera.

```
document.addEventListener('myCameraEvent', handleMyCameraEvent);
```

And I want to trigger this event in angular controller or directive. Could anyone explain, how is it possible to implement with angular?

Comment: That is usually done through directives. What exactly do you want to do with these events?

Comment: You need to set the controller function in the event at the html level like ng-click=fn() or do it through directives as Package mentioned

Comment: @package,I have existed event with name myCustomEvent, registered in document. I want to trigger when this event called and get some value from this event

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a generic custom events observer service:

```
.service('Camera', function($document) {

  //map of current subscribers
  var subscribers = {};

 //notifies all subscribers of particular event type
 function notify(event) {
    var handlers = subscribers[event.type] || [];
    for (var i = 0; i < handlers.length; i++) {
      handlers(i)(event);
    }
  }
  //adds new handler to subscribers list
  //returns object with unsubscribe() method
  this.subscribe(eventType, handler) {
     var handlers = subscribers[eventType] || [];
     handlers.push(handler);
     return (function(type, index) {
       return {
         unsubscribe: function() {
           subscribers[type].splice(index);
         }
       }
     })(eventType, handlers.length - 1);
  }

  //register custom events
  $document.on('myCameraEvent', function(event) {
    notify(event);
  });

  $document.on('myOtherCameraEvent', function(event) {
    notify(event);
  });

});
```

In your controller, you'd use it like this:

```
.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, Camera) {
  subscriber = Camera.subscribe('myCustomEvent', customEventHandler);
  function customEventHandler(event) {
    //process event
    //..

    //if handler is not needed anymore, unsubscribe
    //subscriber.unsubscribe();
  }

})
```

Of course, this is just general idea. You'd might want to have specific methods on Camera service, for example `Camera.onSnapshot(snapshothandler); Camera.onTurnOff(turnOffHandler);` which would register handlers to specific events to abstract away the event names.

Comment: Great answers, I will have  try